# How to store and retrieve checkboxes to session storage in JavaScript without using JQuery, JSON, or any external libraries?

Tags: javascript, html

The following code contains checkboxes with options for different types of food.

If the task is to store checkboxes to session storage and retrieve them at a later time, how does one store and retrieve the checkboxes in JavaScript, but without the use of JQuery, JSON, or any external libraries?

```js
"use strict";

function validate() {
  var result = true;
  var food = getFood();
  if (result) {
    saveFood(food)
  }
  return result;
}

function getFood() {
  var foodType = "unknown";
  var foodArray = document.getElementById("food").getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++) {
    if (foodArray[i].checked) {
      foodType = foodArray[i].value;
    }
  }
  return foodType;
}

function storeFood(food) {
  sessionStorage.food = food;
}

function retrieveFood() {
  switch (sessionStorage.food) {
    case "Pizza":
      document.getElementById("pizza").checked = true;
        break;
    case "Hamburger":
      document.getElementById("hamburger").checked = true;
        break;
    case "Sandwich":
      document.getElementById("sandwich").checked = true;
        break;
  }
}

function init() {
  if (document.getElementById("food-page") != null) {
    retrieveFood();
    document.getElementById("food-form").onsubmit = validate;
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<body id"food-page">
  <form id="food-form" method="post" action="server">
    <fieldset id="food">
      <legend>Foods</legend>
      <p>
        <label for="pizza">Pizza</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="pizza" class="food-choices" name="food-checkboxes" checked="checked" value="Pizza" required="required" />
        <label for="hamburger">Hamburger</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger" class="food-choices" name="food-checkboxes" value="Hamburger" />
        <label for="sandwich">Sandwich</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sandwich" class="food-choices" name="food-checkboxes" value="Sandwich" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I am not a front end developer however when I google ... javascript how to store data between page refresh ... I see approaches which look tempting specifically the SO answer which says :   "This is possible with window.localStorage or window.sessionStorage" ... extremely valuable for you to become confident enough to blast through failed attempts at a solution enough to show blood in the streets before resorting to having to wait for answers here

Comment: JSON is not an external library, its a data format and its also a part of JS

Comment: What a strange tutor... JSON is the preferred way to store data in JS. Well, anyway you can use you own simple data format. I'll see if I can come up with something

Comment: Your tutor sounds pretty ignorant of modern techniques then if you ask me. You could serialise the data to some other format, maybe XML perhaps, but JSON is easier to work with, especially in a JavaScript environment. The only other thing I can think is that part of the assignment is to deliberately make you construct your own data format, or just research other existing ones, but that's a bit of a big ask for the second week of the course if you ask me...have you studied other programming languages before starting JavaScript?

Comment: then show your tutor this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: Anyway the key mistake in your code is `foodType = foodArray[i].value;` ... This keeps overwriting the foodType variable every time the loop runs. So by the end you'll just be left with the last value only. You need to make foodType an array and keep pushing values into it, instead of replacing one value with another. That will get you a list of all checked items

Comment: Then likewise when you retrieve the value from storage you'll need to loop through each item in the array and process each one through the case statement

Comment: No idea why they would delete that, it sounds like perfectly logical approach in theory. Unless the same line was also doing something strange with JSON? I don't know. Not being able to see exactly what you wrote it's hard to say what he might have disliked. Since you're a beginner he ought to have given you some proper feedback though instead of just calling it rubbish. That's very poor teaching.

Comment: P.s. the answer below is very neat but I'm not sure usage of a one-liner involving .map() and arrow functions would pass for something an absolute beginner would write, unless you'd been specifically studying those functions

Comment: You can of course research them easily on the internet (not like when I was a student...lots of trips to the library instead... ahem), so  if you go and learn about them yourself it might be seen as using your initiative, as long as, after researching it, you can confidently explain what each bit of the code does

Comment: You'd have to get the whole item first, I don't think you can query the objects while they are still in storage. Get the whole array out of storage, then loop through it to test each item individually

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/) is not a library, it's a notation. Take some time to read about it.

There are some ways to code that. Below there is a simple example.

Getting all checked inputs and their values:

```
var result = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')).map(a => { return { id: a.getAttribute("id"), value: a.value }; });
console.log(result);
```

Save and retrieving in/from localstorage:

```
var resultInJson = JSON.stringify(result);
console.log(resultInJson);
localStorage.setItem("data", resultInJson);
console.log(localStorage.getItem("data"));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")));
```

Comment: OP is supposed to use session storage rather than localstorage but yeah otherwise this makes sense

Comment: @thezeroandone JSON is supported for most of browsers but you can use a polyfiil function:https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Answer (score 1):

Solution Without JSON considerations :

```
const
  foodForm = document.querySelector('#food-form'),
  StorageName = 'myFoodStorage';

foodForm.onchange=()=>{    // = storeFood
  let CheckList = Array.from(foodForm.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')).map(a=>`${a.id}=${a.checked}`);
  sessionStorage.setItem(StorageName, CheckList.join(','));
}

window.onload=()=>{   // = retrieveFood
  let CheckList = sessionStorage.getItem(StorageName)

  if (CheckList) {
    CheckList.split(',').forEach(e=>{
      let pair = e.split('=');
      document.getElementById('pair[0]').checked = pair[1] === 'true';
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want a more advanced serialization, it should work for any object where all values are strings.

use `sessionStorage.setItem('foods', serialize(foodStates))` to store the states of the checkboxes and use `parse(sessionStorage.getItem('foods'))` to reconstruct it

```js
"use strict";

function sanitize(str) {
  //Split into char array, escape chars and put back together into string
  return str.split('').map(chr => sanitize.map[chr] || chr).join('')
}

function desanitize(str) {
  //Split into char array, escape chars and put back together into string
  return str.replace('\\:', ':').replace('\\;', ';').replace('\\\\', '\\')
}

sanitize.map = {
  '\\': '\\\\',
  ':': '\\:',
  ';': '\\;'
}

function serialize(obj) {
  var result = "";
  for(var prop in obj) {
    result += `${sanitize(prop)} :${sanitize(obj[prop])} ;`;
  }
  //Remove last ' ;'
  result = result.slice(0, -2);
  return result;
}

function parse(str) {
  var obj = {};
  for(var part of str.split(' ;')) {
    var [key, value] = part.split(' :')
    key = desanitize(key)
    value = desanitize(value)
    obj[key] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}

var orgObj = {pizza: "true", hamburger: "false", sandwich: "true"}
console.log(orgObj)
var encodedString = serialize(orgObj)
console.log(encodedString)
var newObj = parse(encodedString)
console.log(newObj)
```